# Filter Edittext to accept word or number that doesn't start with 0

Tags: java, android, filter, android-edittext

what I'm trying to do is to make Editext except only word or number that not start with zero so I did this

```
mPatentNameET.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return src;
                        }
                        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")  ||
                                src.toString().matches("^[123456789][0-9]$")){
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
```

but didn't work well, I want from EditText to accept for example "Test" or "546" , sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it like this :)

```
mPatentNameET.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return src;
                        }
                        if((mPatentNameET.getText().toString() + src).matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")  ||
                                (mPatentNameET.getText().toString() + src).matches("^[123456789][0-9]*$")){
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
```

Comment: What about situation when someone write some text and back to start and write 0?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a TextWatcher. something like this:

```
    mPatentNameET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            String EditTextString= tx.getText().toString();
            if(EditTextString.charAt(0).equals("0")){
                //TODO return when starting with 0
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```